# Ansible playbook check if service is up if not - install something

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

i need to install Symantec endpoint security on my linux system and im trying to write a playbook to do so

when i want to install the program i use ./install.sh -i 
but after the installation when i run the installation again i get this msg:

```
root@TestKubuntu:/usr/SEP# ./install.sh -i
Starting to install Symantec Endpoint Protection for Linux
Downgrade is not supported. Please make sure the target version is newer than the original one.
```

this is how i install it in the playbook

```
 - name: Install_SEP
     command: bash /usr/SEP/install.sh -i
```

I would like if it's possible to maybe check if the service is up and if there is no service then install it or maybe there is a better way doing this.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: what is the command to check if service is up

Comment: well i didn't write it yet.. im not sure how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like below.

```
- name: Check if service is up
  command: <command to check if service is up>
  register: output

- name: Install_SEP
  command: bash /usr/SEP/install.sh -i  
  when: "'running' not in output.stdout"
```

Note: I have used running in when condition : If the service command returns something specific, include that instead of running.

Comment: i get this output.. it worked fine but then it stoped ... i dont understand why...

fatal: [172.17.64.17]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["service", "symcfgd", "status"], "delta": "0:00:00.007976", "end": "2019-10-10 13:49:26.042357", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-10-10 13:49:26.034381", "stderr": "symcfgd: unrecognized service", "stderr_lines": ["symcfgd: unrecognized service"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Comment: May be the service is not present thats why it shows error. You can give ignore_errors: yes for the first task

Comment: well one of the things i want to check is that if there is no service so that he will install the program? will ignore_errors: yes will help ?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"I would like to check if the service is up and if there is no service then install it."*

It's possible to use [service_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html#service-facts-return-service-state-information-as-fact-data). For example to check a service is *running*

```
vars:
  my_service: "<name-of-my-service>"
tasks:
  - name: Collect service facts
    service_facts:
  - name: Install service when not running
    command: "<install-service>"
    when: "my_service not in ansible_facts.services|
                             dict2items|
                             json_query('[?value.state == `running`].key')"
```

To check a service installed use

```
                             json_query('[].key') }}"
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thank very much for the commend, i've went with Ash solution above yours and it worked :)

Comment: but please if you can explain to me what are this ?
 dict2items
 json_query('[?value.state == `running`].key')"